# IOS: Drag and Drop interaction without hiding the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

**Setting:**
I do have a class `MyView` derived from `UIView` which is properly setup for drag (and drop, but drop does not matter for this question). This means that a `UIDragInteraction` has been registered view `view.addInteraction` and the drag and drop action is working fine (the specific drag items and other implementation does not matter).

Let's say the keyboard is shown on screen (for example because a `UITextField` is selected and has become first responder), initiating a drag interaction by touching and dragging the object always dismisses the keyboard. The dismissal takes place after the drag item has been lifted and is moved by the user.

**My quesiton: How can I avoid dismissing the keyboard when a drag interaction takes place?**

**Further investigations:**
I assumed that the drag interaction somehow calls `resignFirstResponder()` for the `UITextField`, but even disabling the `resignFirstResponder` by overriding it in a subclass and let the substitute do nothing does not prevent the keyboard from being dismissed.

Comment: Hello there, is your `UITextField` contained within a UIScrollView?

Comment: @JadGhadry Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

For enable splitView and multitask to custom view(UKWebView) drag and drop interaction

Full Source and Document available 
http://blogs.specialapps.in/SplitView_MultiTasking

.

Answer (score -1):

Say, in your scenario, you have a `UITextField` inside a `UIScrollView` that is selected. You can access the `keyboardDismissMode` from the corresponding `UIScrollView` and set its value to `.none`.

#### Example

Inside your `UIViewController`, declare a reference to the `UIScrollView` and connect it through your storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

Then, inside the `viewDidLoad()` method, set the property as declared above.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure UIScrollView
    self.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .none

}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think `keyboardDismissMode` is intended for dragging the scroll view itself, not for drag operations via `UIDragInteraction`. Also, `.none` option is the default setting for `UIScrollView`. So at least I cannot make this option affect the drag and drop behavior. Am I missing something here?